# Flot Chart with 3 values in tooltip

Tags: charts, tooltip, flot

I would like to create a Flot Chart with tooltip and 3 values inside.
So i created data as follow:

```
var d1 = [[1678780801000,137.00,'test'],....
```

I hoped i could place the tootip with

```
....y=item.datapoint[1].toFixed(2),z=item.datapoint[2];
```

But i only get undefined. Is there a chance to siple fill tooltip only with desired 3rd value ? Thanks for help.

[image: tooltip]

Answer (score 0):

Flot seems to use only numbers in data so i decided to use data1 and data2.